# JSON parsing giving exception in iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

The JSON Data format is given bewlow

```
{ "affectedDate": 1310515200000, "category": "Kultur", "content": "I en festning fra 1600-tallet, ved hjelp av lys, lyd og avansert teknologi mÃ¸tes de besÃ¸kende av synspunkter som kan virker fremmede, de fÃ¥r hÃ¸re sterke, personlige historier og et mangfold av meninger og stemmer.\n
\n
Vi spÃ¸r blant annet:\n
Har SÃ¸rlandskristendommen fÃ¸rt til maktmisbruk og dobbelmoral? \n
MÃ¥ barna oppdras i Guds navn for ikke Ã¥ mangle viktige verdier? og \n
Hvorfor er det bare fÃ¥ som tÃ¸r Ã¥ si hÃ¸yt at de kommuniserer med de dÃ¸de?\n
 \n
â€Himmelen over SÃ¸rlandetâ€ er Vest-Agder-museets stÃ¸rste utstillingssatsing noensinne, og  mer enn 130 mennesker har bidratt.\n
\n
 Velkommen til en tankevekkende utstilling!", "eventId": 14569, "imageId": 14597, "large":  "http://shelf-media.s3.amazonaws.com/7c3f11582bce0b1e153619e436a622da_large.jpg", "main": true, "medium": "http://shelf-media.s3.amazonaws.com/7c3f11582bce0b1e153619e436a622da_gmedium.jpg", "mini": "http://shelf-media.s3.amazonaws.com/7c3f11582bce0b1e153619e436a622da_pmini.jpg", "small": "http://shelf-media.s3.amazonaws.com/7c3f11582bce0b1e153619e436a622da_pmedium.jpg", "thumbWide": "http://shelf-media.s3.amazonaws.com/7c3f11582bce0b1e153619e436a622da_pwide.jpg", "thumbnail": "http://shelf-media.s3.amazonaws.com/7c3f11582bce0b1e153619e436a622da_gsmall.jpg" "title": "Himmelen over SÃ¸rlandet" }





SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/description.html"]];
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *object = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
NSArray *results = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
appDelegate.books1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
appDelegate.dates =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


for (int i=0; i<[results count]; i++) {
    NSDictionary *dictOne = [results objectAtIndex:i];


    //  NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [dictOne objectForKey:@"date"]);
    //  NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [dictTwo objectForKey:@"affectedDate"]);
    //  NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [eventDict objectForKey:@"location"]);


    NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [dictOne objectForKey:@"affectedDate"]);

    NSString*affectedDate=[dictOne objectForKey:@"affectedDate"];
    NSString *category=[dictOne objectForKey:@"category"];






//  Detail *aBook=[[Detail alloc] initWithDate:affectedDate category:];



}
```

Comment: Wat error do u get while u parse ?

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e07dd0'

Comment: are  u getting the data in the results array after parsing...just put an NSLog and chk it out...

Answer (score 0):

This might prove helpful. It's basically a JSON validator to check if your JSON files/code is valid. You might want to give it a go.

http://jsonlint.com/

Edit: I saw your comment. One bug - after thumbnail in your JSON string you have forgotten to put a comma. The other issue is that your content seems to have these special characters that aren't part of the traditional ascii set. I'm not sure on how to handle that

Comment: i have check the json data in this it gives some error the data which i have shown question can you check that and help me out

Answer (score 0):

If this is the error you are getting

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e07dd0'
```

Then you are trying to access an object using `objectAtIndex:` for an `NSDictionary` object instead of a `NSArray`. `NSDictionary` does not support `objectAtIndex:` Please check your response after parsing and then check the type.

Answer (score 0):

If you added JSON as library, Then you need to add **-all_load** to the linker flags.